# Should I mention the title of my published paper in a personal statement even though this paper is not in a top level?

Tags: graduate-admissions, funding, statement-of-purpose

The personal statement is for a scholarship. I want to write about my achievements to prove I am a qualified candidate. But only one of my papers is related to the research area I am applying.

> I have published several academic papers. One of them, ABC, is published in EFG conference.

Neither my paper nor the conference is top level. The conference is just a local conference. I believe most people in selection committee won't hear about them. Should I list their name on my PS given that they are already on my CV?

If I only say "I have published several academic papers.". Most of them are even not related to the research area I am applying for. I think this word would prove nothing.

How to structure the word in this situation?

Comment: I think your description is not specific enough, since a  non-top conference can be either good, fair, or poor, which leads to different answers. Please specify the quality of the conference more concretely.

Comment: Added, just a local conference.

Comment: What does it mean for the conference to be local in this case? That it happens to be held at the same place you are (possibly just that one time or as a recurring thing?) Or that it really was local in the sense that only people from a single university attended it?

Comment: Hi, just people from the same country. So not many people would attend it. And it almost has no impact factor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your tags suggest that this is part of your application for a scholarship to go to graduate school. Thus i'm assuming that you are not already at graduate school but are applying for a scholarship to be able to go?

If this is the case, no one is expecting you to have papers in top venues before you go. I'm my experience any papers at all pre-grad school is going to be a plus for you (assuming you played a leading role in the paper and are not just buried in the middle for ten minutes work you did as a summer placement student).

However, while when I look at graduate applications I am not looking for an extensive publication record, I am looking for signs of commitment/genuine interest to my field. You should use your paper in that way. I would way something like:

> I have published several academic papers. My publication ABC, presented at EFG, demonstrates a long standing interest in X.

Comment: Thank you!!! I think this is a good way to highlight my qualification.